# Conversion of list of strings into list of tuples

Tags: string, list, haskell, tuples

So, I've been studying Haskell so far. I need to convert the list of strings into the list of tuples containing strings so that they would be paired respectively.

Like this:

```
["String1 String 2", "String3 String4", "String5 String6"]
```

into

```
[("String1", "String2"), ("String3, String4"), ("String3, String4")].
```

I haven't actually imagined any code yet, but I don't have a clue how this should work, so I don't really expect anything but just a hint which I could follow.

Anyways, I'm trying to implement it without any external libraries, so linking them wouldn't be very useful.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: My hint is to think about maps and creating a function that would convert a string to a tuple. Edit: if you've never used a functional programming language before, studying how `map`, `filter` and `reduce` work is probably the big clue here.

Comment: Do you really need a list of tuples, or would a list of lists suffice?

Comment: Yeah, I think I definitely need tuples - thus that it would work with the rest of stuff

Comment: I suggest looking into the `words :: String -> [String]` function, and writing a function `foo :: [String] -> (String, String)`.

Comment: The space between "String 2" is a typo? Or is it on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

If there is not a typo in you list, it should be simple as:

```
strToTuple :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
strToTuple = map toTuple

toTuple :: String -> (String, String)
toTuple st = joinWords $ words st

joinWords :: [a] -> (a, a)
joinWords [x, y] = (x, y)
joinWords _ = error "bad input, list should be length 2"
```

> Output:

```
strToTuple ls
=> [("String1","String2"),("String3","String4"),("String5","String6")]
```

> Note, your post has a "String 2" instead of "String2" I'm not sure if it is a mistake or not, but if it is, this should work